# Merge multiple curved lines into one line

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw with TikZ multiple curved lines which are merged into one line? Below is an example how it should look like:

[image]

I tried the following code, but that looks ugly as hell:

```
\draw[] (2.4,5.4) .. controls (2.4,4.2) and (2.8,4.2) .. (7,8.5); 
\draw[] (2,7.6) .. controls (1.8,8.6) and(3,8.5) .. (7,8.5); 
\draw[] (1.55,7.6) .. controls (1.7,8.6) and(3,8.5) .. (7,8.5); 
\draw[] (9.8,4) .. controls (8.5,5) and (8,6) .. (7,8.5); 
\draw[] (7,8.5) .. controls (7,12) and (6,13.5) .. (5,13.5);
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide what you already tried? Maybe an MWE we can improve on?

Comment: Draw them as bezier curves ( I normally use a series of `(pkt1) .. controls ++(ang1:rad1) and ++(ang2:rad2) .. (pkt) ...`, then make sure that the direction of the control point (the two polar coordinates I used) at the "convergens" is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. This kind of drawing can be done with the `to` path operation, its `in` and `out` options to specify incoming and outgoing angles at interesting points, the [`attach arrow` style from Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524935/73317) and... a bit of patience.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta, bending}

% 'attach arrow' style from Schrödinger's cat:
% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524935/73317>
\tikzset{%
    attach arrow/.style={
    decoration={
        markings,
         mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrow/length}/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}%
         \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
        mark=at position {#1-3*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
        mark=at position {#1-2*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@2);},
        mark=at position {#1-1*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@3);},
        mark=at position {#1+\tmpArrowTime/2} with {\coordinate(@4);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrow/length},bend]}]
          plot[smooth] coordinates {(@1) (@2) (@3) (@4)};},
        },
     postaction=decorate,
     },
     attach arrow/.default=0.5,
     arc arrow/length/.initial=2mm,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[attach arrow=0.2, attach arrow=0.83]
    (-6,-2) to[out=45, in=180] (-4,-1) to[out=0, in=180] (-1.7,-1.8)
    to[out=0, in=-95] (0,0) to[out=85, in=0] (-3,2) to[out=180, in=70] (-5,1);
  \draw[attach arrow=0.5] (-6.5,-4) to[out=-30, in=180] (-5.5,-4.2)
    to[out=0, in=180] (-3,-3) to[out=0, in=205] (-1.1,-3)
    to[out=25, in=-95] (0,0);
  \draw[attach arrow=0.3] (-1.5,-8) to[out=110, in=260] (-0.2,-2.5)
    to[out=80, in=-95] (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you!