# Ways to create/reproduce an basic pattern/image via Latex and tools

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach, tikz-pic, pspicture

what would be the (easiest) way to make such a plot/pattern in latex (lua and or xe - possible)

[image]

(would be really nice to adjust the number of sticks and the degree of the lines - as parameters ? kind of for each syntax)

---

(the right latex libs could be totally others .. but ..)

What I saw for now is

- for joining lines  [Merge multiple curved lines into one line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525861/merge-multiple-curved-lines-into-one-line)
- for parallel lines [How to draw a line passing through a point and parallel to another?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19381/how-to-draw-a-line-passing-through-a-point-and-parallel-to-another)

? based on https://texample.net/tikz/examples/membrane-surface/

---

not sure that those structures would be really a latex way to do it

and perhaps the best way would be to take a route via inkscape ?

Could be as easy as it would already exists like in something like the Lindenmayer System lib?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Miyase feel free to add a idea how to achieve a solution (it don't need to be strictly in manual text code ... )

Comment: @InLaw It's nothing against you, it's just the usual rules. Everyone here volunteers on their free time, so it's considered more polite to show some effort before asking people to dedicate time on your problem. Also, LaTeX usage can differ greatly from people to people, so knowing what sort of compiler or packages you're using.

Comment: @Miyase the "This question already has answers here" shows that you are not reading the question at all. That behavior/you need to be banned .. no volunteers would like to waste the time of others which is now the case because of your behavior. Why are you doing that (because of your 1500 points)? 
It is an open question and I don't want be misleading with suboptimal code examples. 
There is an answer but the spread is huge between inkscape, Lindenmayer System, tikz-picture or something better but totally different

Would be nice if you could help regarding the question!

Comment: I'm not the one who closed the question. I simply mentioned that questions that didn't show any starting point with code tended to be closed.

Comment: @Miyase you "simple" added no value for no one. Please answer the question or write nothing.